# Simple element slider animation tool

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation

I'm new to jQuery and I've been messing about with this code, It works but I want to learn how to shorten the code by the eliminating unnecessary repeated code.

Here is a link to [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eSZFD/168/)

## HTML

```
<div id="div1" style="display:none;">one<div id="divb" class="upper">close</div></div>
<div id="div2" style="display:none;">two<div id="divb" class="upper">close</div></div>
<div id="div3" style="display:none;">three<div id="divb" class="upper">close</div></div>
<div id="div4" style="display:none;">four<div id="divb"     class="upper">close</div></div>
</br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br><div class="buttons">
<a class="button" id="showdiv1">Div 1</a>
<a class="button" id="showdiv2">Div 2</a>
<a class="button" id="showdiv3">Div 3</a>
<a class="button" id="showdiv4">Div 4</a>
</div>
```

## JQuery

```
$(function() {
     $('#showdiv1').click(function() {
        $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow');
         $('div[id^=div]').slideUp().delay(1000);
          $('#div1').slideDown('slow').delay(1000);
        
    });
    
      $('.upper').click(function() {
      $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow');
       $('#div1').slideUp('slow');
    });

    $('#showdiv2').click(function() {
        $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow');
         $('div[id^=div]').slideUp().delay(1000);
          $('#div2').slideDown('slow').delay(1000);
        
    });
    
     $('.upper').click(function() {
      $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow');
       $('#div2').slideUp('slow');
    });


     $('#showdiv3').click(function() {
        $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow');
         $('div[id^=div]').slideUp().delay(1000);
          $('#div3').slideDown('slow').delay(1000);
        
    });

     $('.upper').click(function() {
      $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow');
       $('#div3').slideUp('slow');
    });

   $('#showdiv4').click(function() {
        $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow');
         $('div[id^=div]').slideUp().delay(1000);
          $('#div4').slideDown('slow').delay(1000);
        
    });
    
     $('.upper').click(function() {
      $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow');
       $('#div4').slideUp('slow');
    });

})
```

Ok, after much headache - I'm new to this sh#t. I've changed the code to this. All works fine. I would like someone that knows, to give me any tips for improvement, as I'm totally improvising here, thankyou.

jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('a').click(function () {
    var divname= this.name;
    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow');
    $('div[id^=div]').slideUp().delay(1000);
      $("#"+divname).slideDown('slow').delay(1000);

    });

     $('.upper').click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow');
    $('div[id^=div]').slideUp('slow');

  });
    });
```

## More HTML

```
<body>
<div id="div1" style="display:none">
Hello World  <a class="upper" id="div1">close</a>
</div>
<div id="div2" style="display:none">
Test<a class="upper" id="div2">close</a>
</div>
<div id="div3" style="display:none">
Another Test
</div>
<div id="div4" style="display:none">
Final Test
</div>
</br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br>
<div class="menu">
<ul>
<li><a href="#" name="div1" >one</a></li>
<li><a href="#" name="div2" >two</a></li>
<li><a href="#" name="div3" >three</a></li>
<li><a href="#" name="div4" >four</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Code Review. Please post your code in the question as well. Also make sure to check this out: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/faq

Comment: @Yuck: You can't post people code for them. As this page gives away rights via collective comments. You have to ask them to post their own code.

Comment: @Yuck: Obviously it was a well-intentioned edit but Loki's right, and [here are additional reasons why](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/470).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

View all my changes on this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BcTUR/).

### HTML

- Use the *self-closing* tag `<br />` not the *closing* tag `</br>`.
- Your close buttons (`.upper`) are doing a very similar function to your `<a>` tags below, the should both be `<a>` tags. The reason why I wouldn't make them `<div>`s is because you would need to manually add a `tab-index` to enable keyboard accessibility, links come with it.
- I'd use a HTML5 `data-` attribute instead of ID to specify the id of the div you're showing.
- No need to include an id on the close buttons.
- You can add a class to your 'sections' so they can be targeted together.

  ```
  <div id="div1" class="section">
      one
      <a class="hide-div">close</a>
  </div>
  <div id="div2" class="section">
      two
      <a class="hide-div">close</a>
  </div>
  <div id="div3" class="section">
      three
      <a class="hide-div" href="#">close</a>
  </div>
  <div id="div4" class="section">
      four
      <a class="hide-div" href="#">close</a>
  </div>

  <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />

  <div class="buttons">
      <a class="show-div" data-div="div1" href="#">Div 1</a>
      <a class="show-div" data-div="div2" href="#">Div 2</a>
      <a class="show-div" data-div="div3" href="#">Div 3</a>
      <a class="show-div" data-div="div4" href="#">Div 4</a>
  </div>
  ```

### CSS

- Put the `display:none;` style into your CSS.

  ```
  .section {
      height:600px;
      display:none;
  }

  .hide-div {
      display:block;
  }
  ```

### JavaScript

- Target the `.button` class, not `a`. I would also rename `.button` to something a little more descriptive like `.show-div`
- .upper isn't very descriptive, something like `.hide-div` would be better.
- You should only hide and delay the sections if there are any, this gives the user a weird second long pause if there are no sections visible. I've used the `.visible` class to aid with this.
- Pulled the hide sections code out because it's used in multiple places.

  ```
  $(document).ready(function () {
      $('.show-div').click(function () {
          var divId = this.getAttribute('data-div');
          $('html, body').animate({
              scrollTop: 0
          }, 'slow');

          hideSections();

          $("#" + divId)
              .slideDown('slow')
              .delay(1000)
              .addClass('visible');
      });

      $('.hide-div').click(function () {
          $('html, body').animate({
              scrollTop: 0
          }, 'slow');
          hideSections();
      });
  });

  function hideSections() {
      if ($('.visible').length > 0) {
          $('.section')
              .slideUp()
              .delay(1000)
              .removeClass('visible');
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: Thank you Tyriar and Back in a Flash, very helpful. Lots of great tips, I'm very pleased. May the learning curve continue.

Comment: I can't upvote yet as I'm new, thanks again though.

Answer (score 3):

Your newer code is much much better than the previous attempt. Some little fixes that I'd suggest are:

1. Don't use the following

   ```
   $('div[id^=div]').slideUp().delay(1000);
   ```

   as it hides the `close` button inside the div. So, if I open `div1` and click the `div1` again, I can't see the `close` button there.
2. Since you are continually using jQuery, I'd prefer to use `.attr()` method to fetch the name instead of

   ```
   this.name;
   ```

   that you have used inside your new code.
3. You must not bind your `.click()` to the `a` tag. Instead you already have `class="button"` assigned to them. Use it.

Here is an updated [fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/eSZFD/173/) that addresses the issues and fixes them.

### jQuery Code

```
$(function () {
    var newId = "";
    $('.button').click(function () {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: 0
        }, 'slow');
        if (newId !== "") $('#' + newId).slideUp().delay(1000);
        newId = $(this).attr("name");
        $('#' + newId).slideDown('slow').delay(1000);

    });
    $('.upper').click(function () {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: 0
        }, 'slow');
        $(this).parent('div').slideUp('slow');
    });
});
```

Comment: I strongly disagree with number 2. Even though he is using jQuery, jQuery is a framework on top of JavaScript. Why take the effort to create a jQuery object and then call a far slower method to produce the EXACT same result when `this.name` is faster and more accessible.

Comment: @Tyriar To maintain similarity.

Comment: The language being used is JavaScript though. I understand the importance of code consistency, but there is nothing wrong with using simple object properties when you're using jQuery.

Comment: Yup, @Tyriar which is why I mentioned that **I'd prefer to use** as opposed to **you shouldn't**.